# Integrals as limits

Tags: calculus, integration

Can integrals be defined as limits and, if so, is it something like this?

Given $\delta_x=\frac{b-a}{n}$,

$$\int_a^b x^2\;dx≡\lim_{n\mapsto \infty} n(a^2+2a\delta_x+n\delta_x^2)\delta_x$$

Edit 1: removed reference to summation, which I now think was wrong.

Edit 2: added a factor of $\delta_x$.

Edit 3: it seems the idea I was trying to define is Riemann Sums, so that's probably enough for me to go on. Thanks to those who replied.

Comment: Why  would you think that limit gives you the integral? Note that the sum is at least $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na^2$, which is infinite. Note also the overloading of the symbol $n$.

Comment: Integrals can, of course, be defined as limits, namely, as limits of Riemann sums, q.v.

Comment: @GerryMyerson One answer might be: because I don't understand limits very well. Another answer might be: because I understand integration to be the result of summing rectangles as the width of each rectangle tends to $0$ and the number of rectangles tends to $\infty$, which I thought could be represented by as a limit process. I'm unfamiliar with the term 'overloading'; can you clarify?

Comment: Google Riemann Integral ... watch some of the u-tube videos & look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral

Comment: Your understanding of integration, when stated precisely, is the Riemann sum idea I mentioned. "Overloading" means using one symbol (or word, or phrase) to mean two (or more) different things. $n$ is defined by $\delta_x=(b-a)/n$, but then you also used it as a dummy variable in the sum you used to have.

Comment: Of course, now that you don't have a sum any more, the question arises as to how your formula squares with your understanding of integration as a sum.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Interesting question to which I probably don't have an interesting answer at present. Thanks for your help.